# Biorthogonal sequence for monomials in L2(0,1)

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

A sequence $(x_n^*)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a biorthogonal sequence for a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in a Hilbertspace $H$ if
$$ (x_m^*, x_n) = \delta_{mn} $$
for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Does a biorthogonal sequence for the sequence of monomials exist in $L_2(0,1)$?

Comment: If you mean the sequence of all monomials, such sequence does not exist.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. Why doesn't it?

Comment: I have misplaced my first comment. You can find it in the comment section of the answer.